# How can I make my 404 PHP Error Page appear in IIS6?

Tags: php, iis, iis-6, http-status-code-404

I have a PHP script all set up and ready to go that handles malformed URLs gracefully. If the query string it's been passed doesn't correspond to an actual page, it issues a 404 error and displays its own custom error page, which is actually pulled from a Content Manager database.

On Apache this works great. In II6... not so much. I need to know what I need to do to tell IIS6 to not try overriding my PHP 404 error with its own Microsoft default error page.

In my PHP script, the code that handles 404 errors includes this command:

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');
```

When I comment that line out, my PHP error page shows up great. But if I leave it un-commented, all I see is this:

[image: Microsoft's Default Error Page]

I don't want to have my custom error page showing up with a 200 status code; that's misleading to search engines. So how can I leave that line of code above in the code without Microsoft's page getting jammed in there instead?

Comment: IT should show up if you make it large enough. I believe there's a minimum size before IE will display it. A quick google fetched 512 bytes, but I haven't confirmed.

Comment: If the minimum size is as small as you say, then this isn't the problem -- my error page is 3.3 KB!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops - I figured it out. In IIS, in the Properties for the site, I had to go to the "Custom Errors" tab and effectively clear out the pages that were there by default for the 404 errors. Actually you only need to do this on the first one, but it doesn't hurt to do it on the variations as well. There were documents listed there (with Type "File"). I assumed that was the default, but I guess it's not? When I selected those and clicked "Set to Default", then the type switched to "Default" instead of "File", and my PHP script started working as I wanted it to.